# resize webpage on object, in my webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize

I have to insert the contents of a web page (the full page) to another, I made the object, just that I'd need more small and above all without scrolling, i scroll I already removed but when i set the suitable size in the  of the object, it cut a few things, what can I do?
I set the pixel size in the css, but it would have to redo all the work to do it again from scratch smallest, there are other ways?

```
 <object id="event" type="text/html" data="./calendary/index.html" width="370" height="499"> </object>
```

this is the code on the first page, but the dimension of the page that i call is w=420 and h=570

link to codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ygEpWa

Comment: Would be better to provide all the html and css code, can really tell much from that. have you tried `overflow: auto;`

Comment: if i do it all the page bug o.o the page that i speak is: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ygEpWa but i edit much thing..

Comment: Can you provide all the code in question, html css. or a jsfiddle. cheers

Comment: if you go to http://codepen.io/anon/share/zip/ygEpWa/ , download automatically the 3 page(html,css,js) which are more comprehensive than the linked page above

Comment: @WebDevGuy thanks for edit

Comment: no worries, at work atm. will have a look on lunch break

Comment: @WebDevGuy its fantastic, thanks so much! i'll wait :)

Comment: Sorry it's a bit difficult to follow your question, I think what you want is media queries using css. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: @WebDevGuy i add it on the calendary's css, on the top "@media screen and (max-width: 370px) { " but its like before

Comment: sorry having trouble understanding what the problem is exactly, and what the desired outcome is

Comment: @WebDevGuy I wish that calendar appeared to me on the site, on the right, just that there isn't enough space, I would like that covered only the background and not the rest of the site, the calendar is on another html file and to add it, i need to recall and i think to use <object>, but idk if there is another method

Comment: i use the "zoom:x%;" on the calendary's css and i perfectly resize the calendary ( http://image.prntscr.com/image/7540fe9eb4164d3a8533941ae1ea1d73.jpeg ) but, there is a empty space on the top-left and i need to remove this, i try something but without success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I see what your saying but I can't see that in the codepen. 
Try adding this for your css.

```
#calendar {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 570px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(66, 66, 66, 1);
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
  z-index: 100;
}

.week {
  background: #4A4A4A;
  text-align:center;
  width: 100%;
}

.day {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 65px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #4A4A4A;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}

.details {
  position: relative;
  width: 420px;
  height: 75px;
  background: rgba(164, 164, 164, 1);
  margin: 5px auto 0px auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

I tried to replicate the issue here. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mRjwXO

Comment: with this code show like this: image.prntscr.com/image/92049d87fe3248df829a20eb27f56a7c.jpe‌​g now i try to use left and top and on firefox work ( image.prntscr.com/image/aa7ce2c9e7804708ba3362952b3295a8.jpe‌​g ) but on chrome no: image.prntscr.com/image/4b85b8afe62b4768920ada7eac4c3248.jpe‌​g .. now the css code is this: codeshare.io/2pqQO4

Comment: but only work on firefox, idk why on firefox the left and top setting work and on chrome is different, if i change the value to fix on chrome, it will ruin on firefox

Comment: There might be something else affecting the way it displays. right click and inspect the element in the browser. Then uncheck styles for css until you find the probelm

Comment: i try something and, if i delete  position:absolute; on chrome, its perfect but on firefox no.. idk what to try

Comment: Now i solve, i remove left and top and i add the position absolute on body, but also on #calendary, now work! thanks for all your time